# Configurar as margens da Folha no FPDF

Tags: fpdf

Estou com um problema no FPDF, preciso configurar as margens da página, mas não consegui achar como eu faço isso. Se alguém souber e puder me responder obrigado, ou se souberem se já foi perguntado isso aqui no fórum me mandem o link que eu vou olhar.

Comment: Uma pequena pesquisa no Google devia te resolver a questão

Comment: Também não percebo o voto para fechar a pergunta... O downvote fui eu que dei

Comment: Cara não teria vindo aqui se eu tivesse achado no google vc não acha??? tipo to a 2 dias pesquisando isso lá e só me redireciona pra páginas básicas onde ninguém que fez a página se importou em mostrar isso... mas blza..

Comment: @JesseSeffrin fiz a pesquisa em inglês (set margin fpdf) e em português (definir margens fpdf), e em ambos os casos encontrei a resposta com alguma facilidade. Já aí tens a resposta, espero que te tenham ajudado, mas mantenho o meu downvote pelas razões já referidas

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, é importante definir o tamanho da página corretamente ao criá-la:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(210,297)); // P = Portrait, em milimetros, e A4 (210x297)
```

As margens no FPDF dependem do ponto de vista que você está tratando. Temos as margens lógicas, que são uma referência para construir o documento, temos a margem automática do rodapé, configurável, e as margens físicas da impressora, que fogem um pouco da questão.

As margens lógicas você define por esta função:

```
$pdf->SetMargins( 20, 20, 20, 20 );
```

Porém, nada impede que você avance para fora das margens, dependendo da função de desenho que usa.

Esta outra configuração faz com que uma tentativa de desenhar/escrever abaixo de uma certa posição na tela crie uma página nova:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(boolean auto, [float margin]);
```

No caso, você define se quer quebra automática, e em qual distância do rodapé ocorrerá. É util para gerar relatórios, por exemplo, sem se preocupar com o tamanho da folha.

**Importante**: Se você quer margens avançadas para *layout*, como num editor de textos, isto depende exclusivamente da lógica do seu software, usando corretamente as funções dentro das medidas desejadas. As funções nativas do FPDF são apenas para geração dos elementos básicos da página.

Comment: Vlw vou tentar...